# How to map data from two nested arrays in react js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mongodb, redux

Here, I have taken an array named ‘cardItem’ inside another array ‘cart’. Now, I want to map ‘cardItem’ array.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXtxj.png)

```js
 {
                        cart.cardItem?.map(item =><tr >
                            
                            <td></td>
                            <td> <img src={item.image} alt="" className='cart-image order-image' /> <br />
                            <small>{item.name}</small>
                            </td>
                            <td>{item.price}</td>
                            <td>{item.cartQuantity}</td>
                            <td>{item.cartQuantity*item.price}</td>
                        </tr>

                            )   
                        }
```

Comment: can you explain it little bit more?

Comment: Please provide a snippet (not an image) with an example of `cart` so we can use it for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on below assumption of 'cart' being an array,

> - 'cart' array has multiple elements each of which is an object
> - cartItem (within each cart-array element) is an array
> - cartItem-array has elements that have name, image, price props

one possible solution is presented in the code-snippet below:

```js
const cart = [{
    cartQuantity: 1,
    cartItem: [{
      name: 'Item Name 01',
      image: 'someImage.png',
      price: 25
    }, {
      name: 'Item Name 101',
      image: 'someImage.png',
      price: 12
    }]
  },
  {
    cartQuantity: 5,
    cartItem: [{
      name: 'Item Name 02',
      image: 'someImage.png',
      price: 10
    }]
  },
  {
    cartQuantity: 1,
    cartItem: [{
      name: 'Item Name 03',
      image: 'someImage.png',
      price: 50
    }, {
      name: 'Item Name 101',
      image: 'someImage.png',
      price: 18
    }]
  }
];
// 'cart' array has multiple elements each of which is an object
// cartItem (within each cart-array element) is an array
// cartItem-array has elements that have name, image, price props

const getAllItems = (cart = []) => 
  (cart?.map(
    cartObj => cartObj?.cartItem?.map(
      item => ({
        image: item.image,
        name: item.name,
        price: item.price,
        cartQuantity: cartObj.cartQuantity,
        quantityTimesPrice: cartObj.cartQuantity * item.price ?? 0
      }
  /* <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <img src={item.image} alt="" className='cart-image order-image' />
      <br />
      <small>{item.name}</small>
    </td>
    <td>{item.price}</td>
    <td>{cartObj.cartQuantity}</td>
    <td>{cartObj.cartQuantity*item.price}</td>
  </tr> */
))));
// the above will return an array-of-array (of objects). If required, use .flat(), to get a simple array of objects instead.
// for simplicity in reviewing the results, have returned an object instead of JSX/HTML.
console.log(getAllItems(cart));
console.log('as a flat array: ', getAllItems(cart).flat());
```

**Explanation**

- First, iterate through each element in the 'cart' array
- In the above-snippet, each 'cart' array element is processed using 'cartObj'
- For each element in cart array, iterate through the 'cartItem' array
- Now, for each 'cartItem' (simply named 'item' in code-snippet above), gather the name, image, price
- Calculate the product of cartQuantity (from the outer iteration using 'cartObj') and the price (from 'item')

Note:
[?.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [??](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) are the [optional-chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [Nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) operators, respectively.